# How to take the export of Schema all objects metadata with N rows from each table in Oracle DataPump?

Tags: oracle, export, datapump

Sometimes its needed to take a backup of schema metadata of all objects with only limited rows from each table
with Oracle DataPump (export and import).

In my example, I'll take the export of 20 rows from each table with all metadata, you can modify .par accordingly. Will run two export command

1. Export METADATA_ONLY
2. Export N Rows from each table

Also, you can extract the DDL from a dump into a .SQL file.

In this way, we can have the data in a small limited-size file for our testing purpose to import into another database.

Answer (score 1):

#### Create directory in oracle

```
CREATE DIRECTORY dirname AS '/path/path/path';
Grant read,write on DIRECTORY dirname to public;
```

#### First export run for metadata only for a specified schema.

```
expdp Username/password SCHEMAS=SCH_NAME DIRECTORY=DIR_NAME dumpfile=DMP_FILENAME.dmp CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY
```

#### Second export run for 20 rows from each table.

```
vi exp_filename.par
DIRECTORY=ITO_DATA_PUMP_DIR
DUMPFILE=DMP_FILENAME.dmp
LOGFILE=DMP_FILENAME.log
SCHEMAS=USER
INCLUDE=TABLE:"IN(select table_name from dba_tables where owner ='USER')"
QUERY="where rownum < 20"

expdp username/password parfile=exp_filename.par
```

#### Third Export to extract the DDL from an exported .dmp file.

```
impdp Username/password DIRECTORY=DIR_NAME dumpfile=DMP_FILENAME.dmp SQLFILE=exp_rajesh_all.sql
```

**Another example of exporting with multiple queries and keeping only the latest data based on the date column and also can be modified according to your requirements.**

```
DIRECTORY = my_dir
DUMPFILE  = exp_query.dmp
LOGFILE   = exp_query.log
SCHEMAS   = hr, scott
INCLUDE   = TABLE:"IN ('EMP', 'DEPARTMENTS')"

#TABLES    =(scott.emp,scott.dept,scott.salgrade)
QUERY     = scott.emp:"WHERE job = 'ANALYST' OR sal >= 3000"

# Place following 3 lines on one single line:
QUERY     = hr.departments:"WHERE department_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT
department_id FROM hr.employees e, hr.jobs j WHERE e.job_id=j.job_id
AND UPPER(j.job_title) = 'ANALYST' OR e.salary >= 3000)"

# With date filter
QUERY="where change_date > to_date('31-Dec-2020','DD-MON-YYYY')"
```

Note: Above parameter file is not tested but you can use it as a reference. Also, we can add other data pump parameters as per export/import requirements in the .par file.

Comment: It's useful for me, actually, I was exploring such a way for quite a long time to export data with fewer samples of rows for testing purposes in another DB.